# The existence of computable injection

Tags: algorithms

Let $A\in \mathbb N$ be an infinite recursively enumerable set. Prove that there exists a computable injection $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that $\text{rng}f=A$

I'm not quite understand how to prove the existence. This statement doesn't follow immediately from the definitions?

Comment: What definition of r.e. are you using?

Answer (score 1):

How we solve this question depends a bit on how we define "recursively enumerable." The right definition in my opinion is

> A set $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is r.e. if there is some computable partial function $f$ with $dom(f)=A$.

Another definition sometimes given is

> A set $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is r.e. if it is the range of some total computable function $g$ (or is empty).

One reason this is a bit less satisfying is the need for a special case to handle the empty set, but there are other more subtle reasons why the former is preferable.

*(We could also equivalently define a set to be r.e. if it is the range of some partial computable function; it's a good exercise to show that all three of these definitions are in fact equivalent.)*

The latter definition is closer to the property in the question above; however, it still doesn't solve it trivially, since in your problem you want the function to be **injective**. And the former definition is about *domains*, not *ranges*, so is even further from what you want.

---

It might help build intuition to consider the following "injectivization" problem:

- Suppose $h$ is a total computable function with infinite range. Show that there is a *total injective* function $j$ with the same range.

If you use the second definition of r.e. given above, then this is just a more concrete (in my opinion) way to rephrase your problem; if you use the first definition of r.e. given above, then this is a different problem, but still closely related.

Comment: I don't understand why using the second definition is better in this case. I think, this problem should has a very easy solution, because I found this exercise in the list of easy problems.

Comment: @user1223 I would say this problem does indeed have an easy solution - I don't think I implied that it was hard (at least I didn't intend to). As to why the second definition is better, that's not really visible initially; it becomes clearer down the road, when we consider various *generalizations* of recursion theory. For now, feel free to ignore it, I was just editorializing.

Comment: So, I guess that our statement just follows from first definition, isn't it? But I cant explain it for right, I dont know why

Comment: @user1223 No, it doesn't quite; as I explained in my answer, you need to work in the **injectivity** requirement somehow. The definition is **not** immediately equivalent to the property you want. Try to solve the problem at the end of my answer; that's essentially the problem you're working on, but made a bit more explicit.

Comment: Okay, but what is "total injective"? I know, that total computable function is computable function, defined on the whole $\mathbb N$

Comment: @user1223 "Total injective" means "total and injective." So, it's defined on all of $\mathbb{N}$, and it doesn't map any two distinct inputs to the same output. $x\mapsto x^3$ is total injective, and $x\mapsto 7$ is total non-injective.